# React- createRef() Api - this.child.current is null

Tags: reactjs, reference, ref

In order to allow my `parent component` (`JsonFetcher`) to access values from my `child component` (`Display`), I tried using `createRef()` API that just came of this patch 16.3

Following the "Adding a Ref to a class Component" example in [this document](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), here's what I tried in my code:

```
class JsonFetcher extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.child = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            data: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {   
        this.updateContent(this.props.mainUrl)
    }

    updateContent(mainUrl){
        fetch(mainUrl)
            .then((responseJsonAnyUrl) => responseJsonAnyUrl.json())
            .then((responseJsonAnyUrl) => {
                this.setState({
                    mainUrl: mainUrl,
                    jsonObject: responseJsonAnyUrl
                },
                function () {
                    this.timeout = setTimeout(
                        function(){
                            //let ind = this.child.current.getCurrentIndex
                            //tyring to get values from child...
                            //if index === length-1
                                this.updateContent(mainUrl)
                            //else    
                            //retry this function in 5 seconds
                            // 
                        }.bind(this, mainUrl)
                        ,
                        20000)
                }.bind(this))
            })
    }

    interpretJson() {
        /*
        *some code
        */            
        return(
            <Display content={contentListArray} ref={this.child}/>
        )
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.jsonObject){
            return (
                <div>
                    <div> {this.interpretJson()} </div>
                </div>
            )
        }else
            return(
                null
            )                
    }
}
```

So, I created the `ref` in the constructor, linked it to the `child component` `Display`  in the end of `interpretJson()` method and then i'm trying to use the the child method in my `timeOut()` function. However I get the following error:

**"TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentIndex' of null "**

What am I doing wrong that's not letting me call the child methods so I can simulate the pseudo-code I have commented?

(Edit) **Notes**:

- My child component `Display` is not a stateless component, it's a
  class.
- I already tried calling `<Display>` in the render instead but the
  problem remained.

Comment: You're not using `forwardRef()` anywhere?

Comment: To my understanding, I'm afraid it should not be needed, what would be it's utility in this case?

Comment: "Ref forwarding is an opt-in feature that lets some components take a ref they receive, and pass it further down (in other words, “forward” it) to a child." – is this not what you're trying to do?

Comment: Trying binding the `this` context of your `interpretJson` method in the constructor. `this.interpretJson = this.interpretJson.bind(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function to bind this method to the class. This way, the **this** in  `this.child` will bind to the class component

```
interpretJson = () => {
    /*
    *some code
    */            
    return(
        <Display content={contentListArray} ref={this.child}/>
    )
}
```

if the above answer doesn't work then do this

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.interpretJson = this.interpretJson.bind(this);//bind function to class
        this.child = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            data: [],
        }

 }
 interpretJson() {
        /*
        *some code
        */            
        return(
            <Display content={contentListArray} ref={this.child}/>
        )
    }
```

Comment: You'll need some kind of transpiler for this to work. Something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) with the [transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue (I'm using typescript)

```tsx
private modal = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>()

// ...

public componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.modal)
}

// ...

public render() {
// ...
  <div ref={this.modal} className="modal fade"
  // ...
```

Output. From start is null, then is populated after some little time:

[image]

The problem was that in render method I exited early, and ref code was not reached

```tsx
public render() {
  const { data } = this.state

  // here we return early, ref bellow is not reached
  // and in componentDidmount we can't rely on this.modal.current
  // this.modal.current will be populated only if data is not null
  if (data === null) { return null }

  return (
    <div ref={this.modal} className="modal fade"
    // ...
```

same problem in example in bellow example
[image]

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ymvxj5pqmx